# How to export a list of all monitored hosts in Nagios?

Tags: nagios

In Nagios 2 and 3, I'm looking for a way to export a list of all monitored hosts to either CSV or XML or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```
root@box:/etc/nagios3# cat conf.d/hosts/*.cfg | grep "host_name\|address\|alias" |grep -v localhost | perl -ne '$line = $_; 
chomp($line); 
if ($line =~ /host_name(.*)/) {
$match = $1 ;
$match =~ s/ |\t//g; 
print "\n".$match."\t";
}; 
if ($line =~ /address(.*)/) {
$match = $1 ;
$match =~ s/ |\t//g; 
print $match."\t";
}
if ($line =~ /alias(.*)/) {
$match = $1 ;
$match =~ s/^\s+//; 
$match =~ s/\t//g; 
print $match."\t";
}; 
'
```

It ll spit out a tab separated list with hostname, ip address and alias for each host in your nagios config.

Comment: This worked for me, but for some reason the hosts were in another subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not configuring your hosts in `conf.d/hosts` you may try this:

```
grep host_name /var/log/nagios/objects.cache | cut -f3 | sort -u | paste -d, -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MK Livestatus](http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_livestatus.html):

```
echo -e 'GET hosts\nColumns: address' | unixcat /var/nagios/rw/live
```